# How to give the databricks filepath in data factory

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIm52.jpg)[I'm retrieving notebook path using stored procedure then executing that Databricks notebook using data factory but I'm getting error as message": "Invalid notebook_path: {\"effectiveIntegrationRuntime\":\"DefaultIntegrationRuntime (West Europe)\",\"executionDuration\":0,\"durationInQueue\":{\"integrationRuntimeQueue\":1},\"billingReference\":{\"activityType\":\"ExternalActivity\",\"billableDuration\":{\"Managed\":0.016666666666666666}}}. Only absolute paths are currently supported. Paths must begin with '/'.  . Please help me on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZJBV.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] and make your question easy to understand for people that want to help you

Comment: I have inserted notebook path in database when i executed sp it'll give the notebook path by using that i need to execute that databricks notebook. i attached images for reference

Comment: Notebook path was parameterized as below
@string(activity('get_notebook_path').output).
When i gave notebook directly it's executing, facing issue when i pass it as parameterised

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have specified the notebook path in the Databricks activity.

[image]

This is the excepted behaviour in Azure Data Factory.

**Error code:3201**

- **Message:** Missing required field: settings.task.notebook_task.notebook_path.
- **Cause:** Bad authoring: Notebook path not specified correctly.
- **Recommendation:** Specify the notebook path in the Databricks activity.

For more details, refer "[Run a Databricks notebook with the Databricks Notebook activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook)"

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting notebook paths by using stored procedure after that i'm giving notebook path as parameter like this: @activity('sp_file_path').output

Comment: I'm getting notebook paths by using stored procedure after that i'm giving notebook path as parameter like this: @activity('sp_file_path'). but i'm getting error as below
 Only absolute paths are currently supported. Paths must begin with '/'

storedprocedure giving output notebook paths as : /Users/MetaDataUpdate/FiletoDeltatable

Comment: As per my understanding, you cannot use storedproc to get the Notebook path. Could you please debug and check the error message?

Comment: I'm storing notebook paths in metadata table and joining with task table based on taskid will get notebook path from metadata table this process is executing by storedproc. So that storeproc result I'm trying pass as parameter

Answer (score 0):

There are two pieces to this problem:

1. Retrieving the returned value from the stored procedure
2. Using the returned value in the Databricks activity

Part 1:
Please try using your stored proc from inside a Lookup Activity, instead of a Stored Proc Activity.  The difference is that a Lookup Activity expects data to be returned, and exposes that.  Stored Proc Activity does not require data to be returned, and so may not expose any returned values. (See the 'Stored Procedure' option under 'Use Query' in Settings of the Lookup Activity.)

To ease the development / troublshooting process, connect a Set Variable activity to the Lookup Activity.  The Lookup activity returns the data in an array, so lets use an array type variable. `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`.

An array is not suitable for use in the Databricks activity, so lets extract the path from the array.  Connect a second Set Variable activity to the first Set Variable activity, using string type variable.  Use a Debug run and inspect the output of the first Set Variable activity; determine if there is a key-value pair.  In my test case, I had a key-value pair where the key was the empty string.  `@string(first(variables('arrayoutput'))[''])`

Part 2:
Now that the second variable contains the path, lets parameterize and use the Databricks activity.  If you path does not start with '/' then you will need to prepend onw with this dynamic expression `@concat('/',variables('singleoutput'))` in the Notebook path in Settings of the Databricks Notebook activity.